# Rails: Combining Instance Variable, to display unique record with distinct values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

I'm combining two instance variables, but its displaying two of the same values because sometimes each of my instance variable has the same record. How do I only display distinct?

```
  @var1 = Image.tagged_with(params[:tags])
  @var2 = Image.psql_search(params[:tags])

  @Combined = @var1 + @var2
```

@var1 is from `acts-as-taggable` gem, and @var2 is from postgresql full-text.

Comment: Image.tagged_with(params[:tags]) return instance of array?

Comment: you can try: @Combined = @var1|@var2

Comment: @kikicarbonell i tested it out in development and it seems to work, but not yet in production. can you explain what the difference is between `|` and `+`?

Comment: @andrewliu `[1,2]|[2,3] # => [1,2,3]` "Set Union—Returns a new array by joining this array with other_ary, removing duplicates."—http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-7C / `[1,2]+[2,3] # => [1,2,2,3]` "Concatenation—Returns a new array built by concatenating the two arrays together to produce a third array."—http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-2B

Answer (score 0):

Get the unique IDs of the objects and map them to a new array (using OpenStruct in place of ActiveRecord objects here for example):

```ruby
@combined = [OpenStruct.new(:id => 1), OpenStruct.new(:id => 1), OpenStruct.new(:id => 2)]
#=> [#<OpenStruct id=1>, #<OpenStruct id=1>, #<OpenStruct id=2>]
@combined.map(&:id).uniq.map {|x| @combined.find {|y| y.id == x}}
#=> [#<OpenStruct id=1>, #<OpenStruct id=2>]
```

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-uniq
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-c-new

*This solution doesn't address original database queries, and only addresses presentation issues.*